# Relation between rank and number of distinct eigenvalues of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $T : V\to V$ be a linear transformation such that $\dim\operatorname{Range}(T)=k\leq n$, where $n=\dim V$. Show that $T$ can have at most $k+1$ distinct eigenvalues.

I can realize that the rank  will correspond to the number of non-zero eigenvalues (counted up to multiplicity) and the nullity will correspond to the 0 eigenvalue (counted up to multiplicity), but I cannot design an analytical proof of this.

Thanks for any help .

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349907/what-is-the-relation-between-rank-of-a-matrix-its-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Since the nullity of $T$ is $n-k$, that means that the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda=0$ as an eigenvalue of $T$ is $n-k$; hence, the algebraic multiplicity must be at least $n-k$, which means that the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is of the form $x^{N}g(x)$, where $N$ is the algebraic multiplicity of $0$, hence $N\geq n-k$ (so $n-N\leq k$), and $\deg(g) =n-N$. Thus, $g$ has at most $n-N$ distinct roots, none of which are equal to $0$, and that means that the characteristic polynomial of $T$ has exactly:
$$1 + \text{# distinct roots of }g \leq 1 + n-N \leq 1 + k$$
distinct eigenvalues.

Note that in fact we can say a bit better that $T$ has at most $\min\{k+1,n\}$ distinct eigenvalues (when the rank is $n$).

Comment: I think you mean "where the rank is $k$" at the end?

Comment: $0$ is also an eigenvalue.

Comment: @Kuo What point are you trying to make? I am mystified...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin oh, I mean the 1 in k+1 is for 0

Answer (score 14):

Here is an outline of one way to solve the problem.

- Eigenvectors for distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent.
- Eigenvectors for nonzero eigenvalues are in the range of $T$.
- The range of $T$ cannot contain a linearly independent set with more than $k$ vectors.