# Eigenvalues of $A^tA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A_{m \times n}, n>m, AA^t =\alpha I , \alpha> 0$, and rank A = m , what can we conclude about eigenvalues of $A^tA$ ?

Like we can conclude information about $AA^t$ of order $m \times m$ that since its a diagonal matrix so the eigenvalues will be the elements on the diagonal which is $\alpha$ with multiplicity $m$.But how to conclude that $A^t A$ has $\alpha$ as one eigenvalue of multiplicity $m$ and eigenvalue $0$ of multiplicity $n-m$?

Comment: [Very related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087064/non-zero-eigenvalues-of-aat-and-ata) if not duplicate.

Comment: But how to think of the zero eigenvalue?

Comment: One way: $A^tAx=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $x^tA^tAx=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\|Ax\|^2=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $Ax=0$. Other way trivial, so any nonzero solution to $Ax=0$ is an eigenvector wrt zero eigenvalue. How "many" solutions can you get? Rang-nullity theorem: a subspace of dimension $n-m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well!  It is clear from the link in the comments that if $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of $A A^T $ then it is also the eigenvalue of $A^T A$.

Recall that rank($A  A^T$)=rank($A^T A$) always holds and rank of a matrix is atleast the no. Of nonzero eigenvalues.

Hence, the only way you can manage the rank is to take all other eigenvalues to be zero i.e with n-m multiplicity.

Comment: How eigenvalues of $AA^t$ and $A^tA$ are the same?, as I thought of $(AA^t)^t = AA^t$?

Comment: Haven't you checked the link above , in the comments, I can explain @BAYMAX

Comment: Yes, i got that but how to think of the zero eigenvalues?

Comment: perhaps you meant non-zero distinct eigenvalues? here -https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146927/relation-between-rank-and-number-of-non-zero-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix

Comment: Since it has m non-zero eigenvalues then if any of those remaining eigenvalues is non-zero then the rank ($A^T A$ ) will be m+1(atleast) which cannot be true as  it should also be m, Hence all other eigenvalues must be zero.

Comment: well I am getting the point, thank you!!